# Any way to create and insert data via query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to create a table and insert data into it using a single query in MS Access.

```
student_id | roll_no  | name
-------------------------------
    1      |   1      |  Ankit
    2      |   2      |  Ziyan
    3      |   3      |  Nameer
```

Is there anyway for this ?

Comment: data you want to insert from other table ?

Comment: no, just create the table and insert individual data at the same time

Comment: as far as i know you cannt perform ddl and dml operation from outside of db console. However you can insert multiple record at a same time after creation of table

Comment: Because if you are executing multiple query separated by semicolon then it will consider as separate only. So if you want to execute query from java then simply you can store all queries into stringbuilder and run it through executeupdate()

Comment: Where is the data coming from?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Make Table query in Access (Create tab -> Query Design -> Make Table), you can enter a name for each of your columns, then when you hit Run it will prompt you for the values for each column. Run as many times as you need to insert all your rows.

Answer (score 0):

Althought limited to one query this can be done by [Select.Into](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/select-into-statement-microsoft-access-sql).

```
SELECT Employees.* INTO [Emp Backup] FROM Employees;
```